# Application timeout when saving a large file in rails using dragonfly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, dragonfly-gem

I am having trouble saving a large file, using a model with the dragonfly extension 'image_accessor'.

We are trying to save the file to an Amazon S3 server, using fog and excon.  On this save, we receive the error:

```
A Excon::Errors::Timeout occurred in batch_uploads#upload_file:

 write timeout reached
 excon (0.14.2) lib/excon/socket.rb:124:in `rescue in write'
```

I suspect that the error is related to this: https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly/issues/207 but I can't be totally sure.

Does anyone have any advice on how to move forward with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be an Excon timeout. You can try to increase the [Excon lib's default write_timeout](https://github.com/geemus/excon/blob/master/lib/excon.rb#L24) setting.

```
Excon.defaults[:write_timeout] = 500
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked great when I put that in /config/initializers